# Automate InfoPath form design tasks?

Tags: infopath

I'm currently designing a rather complex InfoPath form for a client.  In the future, the client is going to need to be able update the form themselves, but the complexity of dealing with all the rules and conditional formatting is too much for them.

Is there any way for me to automate a routine design task in InfoPath designer, such as adding a few new fields and linking them to controls on the form?

Ultimately, it would be nice if my client could just type something in a text box and hit a button, then all the predictable and tedious design work to update the form would be done automatically.

Thanks

Comment: **No you cannot script stuff in InfoPath.** Your question does not belong on Stackoverflow though, but on superuser.com. SO is for programming related questions.

Answer (score 0):

Use template parts. They can be created in InfoPath and are used for repetitive tasks where the same controls, data fields, etc are used over multiple forms. I believe they even include data validation, rules, and formatting. It is basically like inserting a mini InfoPath form into another one as a section. The help file in IP explains the steps but no code is involved and it is fairly easy.